# Addinng an offset for content height to animate onhover slide up effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to offset a block with title and description above a picture by the height of the description content. Consider this picture:

[image]

Both titles should be visible by default but on hover description should slide up. I don't know the exact height of the slide, because the length of the content may change. I cannot find the correct offset even with js on page load because it seems incorrect, I assume due to fonts loading a little too slow, thus changing the height of content after page load complete.

I can change the HTML as I need, so I tried separating upper and lower content like so:

```
<div style="background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/175x175)">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="team-meta">
      <div class="block-title"><p>TITLE PRESIDENT</p></div>
      <div class="team-name">TITLE PRESIDENT</div>
    </div>
    <div class="team-description">On Hover, darken overlay and add a brief one sentence description of the person if desired.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And adding these styles:

```
.team-meta {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; /*always at the very bottom of the block*/
}
.team-description {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%; /*always right below the block*/
}
```

This way on page load the description is hidden by default, but now it is difficult to display it on hover. I have to calculate the following:

> For description: top: [height of parent] - [height of the description]
>
> For title: bottom: [height of the description]

Which is quite inconvenient. I have a feeling there should be a trick to make all this much easier and possibly in many less steps.

I achieved something with the following code, which is a disaster, by the way:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.team-container').forEach((e) => {
  anime({
    targets: e.querySelector(".team-description"),
    top: e.querySelector('.wrapper').offsetHeight - e.querySelector('.team-description').offsetHeight + "px"
  }); 
  anime({
    targets: e.querySelector(".team-meta"),
    bottom: e.querySelector('.team-description').offsetHeight + "px"
  });
});
```

I experience an issue here, because the animejs seems to incorrectly convert 100% into the PX value when animating the transition and the block seems to come from the top, instead of the bottom, where it originally was.

I feel like this issue can be trivially solved, but I don't see a way out yet.

Comment: Might want to look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: @TravisJ Thank you. BoundingRect returns position relative to the viewport, I can't see any use for it in this project as the content I'm talking about will be far below the viewport on page load.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it was my fail, or I am not sure what happened. But the script below suddenly returns the correct value for offsetHeight. So using a container I managed to manipulate the whole block using a single animation of margin. Now it simply makes sense!

I still have a feeling this could be done without JS intrusion, but I couldn't figure it out.

```
(function () {

document.querySelectorAll('.team-container > div').forEach((e) => {

  let offset = e.querySelector('.team-description').offsetHeight;

  e.querySelector(".team-card").style.marginBottom = -offset + "px";
}

}());
```